# cassandra paging and hash numbers

Tags: hash, cassandra, paging

i want to use slice query in cassandra like this:

```
create table users (KEY varchar PRIMARY KEY, data varchar);
insert into users (KEY, 'data') values ('1', 'one');
insert into users (KEY, 'data') values ('2', 'two');
insert into users (KEY, 'data') values ('3', 'three');
insert into users (KEY, 'data') values ('4', 'four');
select * from users;
  3 | three
  2 |   two
  1 |   one
  4 |  four
select * from users LIMIT 1;
  3 | three
select * from users WHERE KEY > '3' LIMIT 1;
  2 |  two
select * from users WHERE KEY > '2' LIMIT 1;
  1 |  one
select * from users WHERE KEY > '1' LIMIT 1;
  4 | four
```

in this example partitioner is ordered.but my partitioner is unordered.so i use query like this:

```
select * from users WHERE token(KEY) > token('3') LIMIT 3;
```

if i want to access all rows i have to start queries from key with lowest hash number.
is there any way to find key with lowest hash number? if not is there a better way to paging through table row's?

thank for your help :)

edit:

now i have another problem.token function is only supported on partition key.and in my cf primary key is compound as (word,docid).so for example i have severel word=hi.and when i use query like select * from users WHERE token(word) > token('hi') LIMIT 3; it start from last hi in my cf and in this way some rows with word=hi has been ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Your first query can have no `WHERE` and it will return the first keys, ordered by hash.  You can then use the last key returned by that in the next query.

You can also use `token('')`, which evaluates to the lowest token i.e.

```
select * from users WHERE token(KEY) > token('') LIMIT 3;
```

will return the first 3 keys ordered by token and is equivalent to

```
select * from users LIMIT 3;
```

You can also make use of the new automatic paging in Cassandra 2.0 (see [CASSANDRA-4415](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4415)).

Comment: thanks for your help. but now i have another problem.token function is only supported on partition key.and in my cf primary key is compound as (word,docid).so for example i have severel word=hi.and when i use query like select * from users WHERE token(word) > token('hi') LIMIT 3; it start from last hi in my cf and in this way some rows with word=hi has been ignored.

Comment: You can restrict within the row, but it sound like the automatic paging in Cassandra 2.0 will do what you need.

Comment: can you explain more about automatic paging in Cassandra?

Comment: You can run `select * from users;` and read the results. Behind the scenes it is paging the results for you so you don't need to store all the results in memory and you can start processing while the results are still coming.

Comment: It's automatic! But you need Cassandra 2.0.